# I have too fix something in my Copy&Paste program in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pmw

This is my Copy&Paste program:

```
from tkinter import *
import Pmw
class CopyTextWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        Pmw.initialise()
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title("ScrolledText Demo")
        self.frame1=Frame(self, bg="White")
        self.frame1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.text1=Pmw.ScrolledText(self, text_width=25, text_height=12, text_wrap=WORD,
                              hscrollmode="static", vscrollmode="static")
        self.text1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

        options = ["Copy", "Paste"]
        self.selectedOption = StringVar()

        self.menu = Menu(self.frame1, tearoff=0)

        for option in options:
            self.menu.add_radiobutton( label=option, variable=self.selectedOption,
                                   command=self.ExecuteOption)

        self.text1.bind("<Button-3>", self.popUpMenu)

    def popUpMenu(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def ExecuteOption(self):
        if self.selectedOption.get()=="Copy":
            self.CopiedText=self.text1.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
        else:
            self.text1.settext( self.text1.get()+self.CopiedText)

def main():
    CopyTextWindow().mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

In this program, I want to make a GUI, that in it you can copy and paste text that you have selected. when you press the right mouse button, a little menu with the Copy and Paste options.

The program opens up, but when I press the right mouse button, no menu appears. Python also doesn't complain with an error.

I need to understand my mistake in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reason I ignore, the event doesn't seem to be triggered when the bind is on the Text or on the Frame, but it works when it's on the main window:

```
from tkinter import *
import Pmw
class CopyTextWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # I've added a master option to pass to the frame
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Pmw.initialise()
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title("ScrolledText Demo")
        self.frame1=Frame(self, bg="White")
        self.frame1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.text1=Pmw.ScrolledText(self, text_width=25, text_height=12, text_wrap=WORD,
                              hscrollmode="static", vscrollmode="static")
        self.text1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

        options = ["Copy", "Paste"]
        self.selectedOption = StringVar()

        self.menu = Menu(self.frame1, tearoff=0)

        for option in options:
            self.menu.add_radiobutton( label=option, variable=self.selectedOption,
                                   command=self.ExecuteOption)

    def popUpMenu(self, event):
        print("ok")
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def ExecuteOption(self):
        if self.selectedOption.get()=="Copy":
            self.CopiedText=self.text1.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
        else:
            self.text1.settext( self.text1.get()+self.CopiedText)

def main():
    # main window
    root = Tk()
    ctw = CopyTextWindow(root)
    # bind on the main window
    root.bind("<Button-3>", ctw.popUpMenu)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```